# How can I ignore libxml HTML Parsing error

Tags: c++, libxml2

I'm using libxml to parse and build a tree from html:

```
htmlDoc = htmlParseDoc((xmlChar*)s.c_str(), "windows-1252");
```

s contains the HTML in a string. I am using curl to retrieve the HTML and storing it in s. The functionality is working exactly as I want however I just want to remove the htmlParsing errors from being output to the console:

```
HTML parser error : htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <body> tag 
<html><head><title>UPC-E Home Page</title></head><body topmargin=8 leftmargin=8
```

I get these errors because every once in a while curl will timeout and won't be able to retrieve the entirety of the HTML. This is fine, I just want to ignore it and try again. However, I don't want the user to see these errors. How can I disable these from being output to the user?